# Помогите с SystemBarTint

Tags: java, android, инспекция-кода

Помогите с SystemBarTint. Хочу сделать как здесь: https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Вроде должно работать, но не работает. (вернее работает, но эффекта нет)....Может мой косяк...Гляньте глазком...

```
public class Cinema4d_page1 extends Fragment {

    public final static String TAG = Cinema4d_page1.class.getSimpleName();

    private WebView webView;
    private TextView text;

    public Cinema4d_page1() {
    }

    public static Cinema4d_page1 newInstance() {
        return new Cinema4d_page1();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        webView.saveState(outState);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webViewCinema4d1);
        webView.setClipToPadding(false);
        setInsets(getActivity(),webView);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema4d_page1_layout, container, false);

        text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webtextview1);

        ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nf != null && nf.isConnected() == true) {
            webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewCinema4d1);

            WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
            ws.setSupportZoom(true);
            ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            // ws.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://*******");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_internet_please, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "KShYJgLB.ttf"));
            text.setText(R.string.not_internet);

        }

        return rootView;
    }

    public static void setInsets(Activity context, View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) return;
        SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(context);
        SystemBarTintManager.SystemBarConfig config = tintManager.getConfig();
        view.setPadding(0, config.getPixelInsetTop(true), config.getPixelInsetRight(), config.getPixelInsetBottom());
    }
}
```

=======xml=========

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"       
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LayoutHome1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webViewCinema4d1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutHome2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/webtextview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Поговаривают, что этот эффект нужно делать для Главного активити, и только тогда он работает...